# Display TinyMCE Content in React

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, react-hooks

As per title, what I'm trying to achieve is to display the Wysiwyg content from the Editor to another component.

I created a sample on codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-tharp-zwflu

As you can see, the editor works fine and is returning the values as it should.

My issue here is I'm not able to convert that String I get returned, into JSX tags.

I did a deep search, but couldn't find anything related.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: i need answer too, wasted my whole day searching for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install
`npm i react-html-parser`
import it to your component
`import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";";`
and render it

```
<div className="wysiwyg">
{ReactHtmlParser(wysiwyg)}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Anna, at the end I've been able to find the solution (which you can see on the other answer) - But thank you anyway for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

I actually found the solution at the end, sorry for not having updated it already!

Here the answer I got from TinyMCE for this issue: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react/issues/138

So, you should use directly a parser, in this case react-html-parser will do the job.

I created another codesandbox so you can directly have a look at the working copy: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-greider-dl2mv

Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually on 2023-10-02 is not working correctly something is with dependencies (last relies is 6 years ago)
so anyone who read this use `html-react-parser` instead.

Here is the dependency problem with  `react-html-parser` discussed and found soulution
[Unable to resolve dependency for installing html-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185391/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-installing-html-parser)